# Rails root not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Unicorn and Nginx for my rails app with PostgreSQL for the db, and I've been running into a problem. When I go to the root of my site in the browser (my own domain name), it displays the "tasks" scaffold page rather than the view indicated by "pages#index". I'm not sure what the problem is, I'm also rather new to this so I apologize if my explanation isn't clear, just let me know.

routes.rb

```
root 'pages#index'

resources :tasks
```

rake routes:

```
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         pages#index
    tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)          tasks#index
          POST   /tasks(.:format)          tasks#create
 new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)      tasks#new
edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
     task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#show
          PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
          PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
          DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#destroy
```

After looking at other similar questions, I just want to say that there is no "index.html" in public.

My app/view/pages/index.html.erb consists of a single paragraph element with "hello".

EDIT: Also the problem has now changed, it is showing the "hello" page but when i refresh it switches to the tasks page and alternates like this. What is going on?

EDIT2: The problem seems to have been fixed now. I rebooted the server and the problem seems to have gone away. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does `log/development.log` say when you make that request for `/`?

Comment: What does your `PagesController#index` action contain?

Comment: At one point was your root path tasks#index? If so did you restart your server after changing your routes?

Comment: A successul request should include the action and params as well as the controller. Make sure these are correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: Also the problem has now changed, it is showing the "hello" page but when i refresh it switches to the tasks page and alternates like this. What is going on?

Comment: The problem seems to have been fixed now. I rebooted the server and the problem seems to have gone away.